# Css box model column height overlap

Tags: html, css

I have the Css box model codes below which try to create 3 column layout with same height. It should also be responsive.

```
<header>Header</header>  <content>
<div class="column columnLeft">
      <h2>Column Left</h2>
</div>
<div class="column columnMiddle">
  <h2>Column Middle</h2>
</div>
<div class="column columnRight">
  <h2>Column Right</h2>
</div> </content><footer>Footer</footer>
```

Here is Css code. It seems that the problem is in the content. It pushes the footer more than desired.

```
    *{ box-sizing:border-box;}
     html,body{  margin: 0;padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
     }
       header{
      background:#000;
      color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     height: 50px;
     }
     content{
      margin: 0 auto;
       overflow: hidden;
      min-height: calc(100vh - 0px);
     height:auto !important;
        overflow-y: auto;
       }
       .column{
       width: 33.333%;
       float: left;
       text-align: center;
       padding:1rem;
       min-height: 100%;
       overflow-y: hidden;
     }
     .columnLeft{
        background: #ccc;
      }
      .columnMiddle{
      background: #fff;
             }
          .columnRight{
           background: #ccc;
            }
           footer{
          background:#000;
          }
               @media only screen and (max-width:768px){
            .columnLeft, .columnMiddle{
        width:50%;
        }
    .columnRight{
        width:100%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
    .column{
         float: none;
         width:100%;
        }
        }
```

the problem is it overlapping the page and vertical scroll appears.

https://codepen.io/mkltkn/pen/LeWrzO

Comment: reduce the height of column ... take heiht of footer and header into consideration

Comment: give your footer a height and a clear:left, then add display: block to your content and set calc to be 100% - (height of header + height of footer)

Comment: @MarouenMhiri no need clear:left as there is already `overflow:auto`

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are a genius. Just do help others and stop niggling

Comment: If I add display:block; columns are shrinking I want the columns stretch to the footer.

Comment: add height: 100% for .column

Comment: The `<content>` element doesn't exist in HTML, so it is treated as unknown element and has `display:inline` by default, which means that height properties are ignored for it.

Answer (score 0):

add "max-width: 33.333%" to your css in your column class. Put it below your width: 33.333%. This way it will default when necessary. See example below

```
.column{
  width: 33.333%;
  max-width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding:1rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problemis in .column class it pushes the footer. I fixed it to change the min-height: calc(100vh - 0px);

```
 content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 0px);
    height:auto !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
   }
   .column{
    width: 33.333%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding:1rem;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 0px);
    overflow-y: hidden;
 }
```